# Create directories from lines of a file

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, directory, cat, mkdir

I'm `cat`ing a file, and the output is something like this:

```
Help me my friend
Temptation
Sorrow
True Love
Vanilla Sky
I was here
SOS
...
```

I'm trying to create directory of all of these lines.

What I have tried is:

```
mkdir `cat x.txt`
```

But the result is a mess! For instance, `I was here` will be split into three directories like `I`, `was`, and `here`. How can I fix this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the lines one by one and use proper quoting:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do mkdir -- "$name"; done <x.txt
```

Comment: Wow, great quick answer thanks a million. Shall I ask you to explain what it does? And shall I ask you to tell me what if I wanted to do the same thing with the out-put of a command??

Comment: @ParsaX Do: `<your_command> | while ...; do ...; done`